# using GoogleTest from a dynamically opened library without access to caller's main

Tags: c++, c++20, googletest

I have a project *(service)* where my code is in a **library** which will be **dynamically opened** by a process from another project *(framework)* that I can't modify. I want to find **a way to trigger the tests** even though I can't modify the `main()`.

The *framework* (not my code) implements a `fmk_process` which finds a `service_lib.so` (containing my code) from a configuration. Many such service libraries can exist for many different applications/backends. As part of `fmk_process`'s initialization, it will call an `extern "C" ServiceInit(...);` from `service_lib.so` which purpose is to *register callbacks* using *templates provided by the framework*. It will complete other initialization tasks after that.

Then, the normal interaction with `fmk_process` is to send a payload on a port it listens to, the internal logic will find the callback and invoke it with the payload. Also, the payload is custom and has all its constructors `private` or `= delete` in the framework...

**how am I supposed to test my service ?**

---

simplified example code to understand:

**framework.h** (visible to service projects)

```cpp
class Service;

class CustomPayload {
public:
  CustomPayload() = delete; // other constructors/factories are not available either
};

class PayloadInvoker {
public:
  virtual void invoke(Service& service, CustomPayload& payload) = 0;
  virtual std::shared_ptr<Service> createService() = 0;
};

class IRegistry {
public:
  virtual ~IRegistry() = default;
  virtual void register(std::string& serviceName, std::shared_ptr<PayloadInvoker> pInvoker) = 0;
  virtual void invoke(std::string& serviceName, CustomPayload& payload) = 0;
};

class Registry {
public:
  Registry();
  ~Registry() {}
  template <typename T> register(std::string& serviceName, void (T::*method)(CustomPayload& payload));
  void invoke(std::string& serviceName, CustomPayload& payload);

private:
  template <typename> class PayloadInvokerTemplate;
  std:shared_ptr<IRegistry> _pImpl;
};

template <typename T> Registry::PayloadInvokerTemplate : public PayloadInvoker {
public:
  PayloadInvokerTemplate(void (T::*method)(CustomPayload& payload)) : _method(method) {}
  std::shared_ptr<Service> createService() { return std::make_shared<T>(); }

protected:
  void invoke(Service& service, CustomPayload& payload) {
    (static_cast<T&>(service).*_method)(payload);
  }
  void (T::*_method)(CustomPayload& payload);
};

// the template which is actually used by the service_lib.so code
template <typename T> Registry::register(std::string& serviceName, void (T::*method)(CustomPayload& payload)) {
  this->_pImpl->register(serviceName, std::make_shared<PayloadInvokerTemplate<T>>(method));
}
```

**framework.cpp** (*not* visible to service projects)

```cpp
#include "framework.h" // there are other includes obviously

class RegistryImpl : public IRegistry {
public:
  void register(std::string& serviceName, std::shared_ptr<PayloadInvoker> pInvoker) override {
    this->_map[serviceName] = pInvoker;
  }
  void invoke(std::string& serviceName, CustomPayload& payload) override {
    if (this->_map.contains(serviceName)) {
      PayloadInvoker* pInvoker = this->_map[serviceName].get();
      std::shared_ptr<Service> pService = pInvoker->createService();
      pInvoker->invoke(*pService, payload);
    }
  }

private:
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<PayloadInvoker> _map;
};

Registry::Registry() { _pImpl = std::shared_ptr<IRegistry>(new RegistryImpl()); }
void Registry::invoke(std::string& serviceName, CustomPayload& payload) {
  this->_pImpl->invoke(serviceName, payload);
}
```

other hidden *framework* code for `fmk_process`

```cpp
int main() {
  // dlopen on service_lib.so
  // dlsym on "ServiceInit"
  // call ServiceInit() with an instance of Registry
  // other init

  // listen on port
  // call registryInstance.invoke(...)
}
```

now my code **service.cpp**, resulting in `service_lib.so`

```cpp
class MyService1 : public Service {
public:
  void MyCallback1(std::string& serviceName, CustomPayload& payload) { /* do something */ }
  void MyCallback2(std::string& serviceName, CustomPayload& payload) { /* do something else */ }
};

class MyService2 : public Service {
public:
  void MyCallback3(std::string& serviceName, CustomPayload& payload) { /* do something */ }
  void MyCallback4(std::string& serviceName, CustomPayload& payload) { /* do something else */ }
};

extern "C" ServiceInit(Registry registry) {
  registry.register<MyService1>("service1", &MyService1::MyCallback1);
  registry.register<MyService1>("service2", &MyService1::MyCallback2);
  registry.register<MyService2>("service3", &MyService2::MyCallback3);
  registry.register<MyService2>("service4", &MyService2::MyCallback4);
}

// somewhere, somehow
TEST(MyServices) {
  EXPECT_TRUE(/* all works */);
}

// particularly this part
::testing::InitGoogleTest();
RUN_ALL_TESTS()
```

**So how can I trigger those tests ?**
In my CI, I could start `fmk_process` and make it find `service_lib.so`, but how am I supposed to call `RUN_ALL_TESTS()` ?
If I have to send a payload on the port using an external process like `curl`, I don't consider it a unit test, and I don't want to write a testing library relying on exchanging requests/responses.

*What I'm not showing here is that I'm actually extending the framework with my own templates using the framework templates. So I need to test that callbacks registered through my templates can be reached properly by `fmk_process`, and particularly, I need to test new versions of the framework and make sure that the templates in my lib are still compatible. If I were to reproduce and mock the framework behavior, I would not be able to test that they are still compatible when the framework evolves (which happens quite often).*

Comment: Compile your code to a static lib, then use that lib in your unit tests, and then link the dll based on your static lib? And then let your test make the same calls as your main would do. In other words your tests will have to run in an executable seperate from the real service. In other words your unit tests run in an executable that is NOT the final product executable.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I can use my service lib and the framework lib to some extent. What I can not do is recreate the logic from the executable in my own executable for 2 reasons: Firstly, the objects from the framework are not constructible from outside the framework (like `CustomPayload` here), and secondly, that would not protect me against changes in the framework. I need to know that during early tests, not much later during validation or worst during deployment

Comment: Looks like the design of this framework makes unit testing impossible. Like you said, you can write some scripts and run integration tests by sending the actual payload through the network, but that's it, I don't see the possibility to directly test `MyService1::MyCallback1` if you can't create your own `CustomPayload`. The workaround I can suggest is to make a template `MyCallback1(std::string& serviceName, T& payload)`, register it with `CustomPayload` type, and test it with your own fake `MyCustomPayload` that has similar interfaces.